# SignalR 2 does not generate /signalr/hubs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

Here is the page:

```
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    <!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.-->
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
            var notification = $.connection.notificationHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
            notification.client.addNewMessage = function (message) {
                // Add the message to the page.
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>'
                    + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
            };
            // Set initial focus to message input box.
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub.
                    chat.server.send($('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
        // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
        function htmlEncode(value) {
            var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
            return encodedValue;
        }
    </script>
```

Here is the hub class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace AdminWebApp.Hubs
{
     [HubName("notificationHub")] 
    public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {

        public void SendNotification(string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addNewMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(AdminWebApp.Startup))]
namespace AdminWebApp
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to access: `http://localhost:4551/signalr/hubs` I get a HTTP 404 not found error and when I try to run the page I get:

```
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined
```

I have tried this: [signalR : /signalr/hubs is not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17422023/signalr-signalr-hubs-is-not-generated) and it didnt work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Global.asax file on the Application_Start event you have to register the hub url.

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
    }
```

Comment: That is only required in SignalR 1 and gives and Error in SignalR 2: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/releases/upgrading-signalr-1x-projects-to-20

Comment: This line is missing app.MapSignalR();

Comment: Adding: app.MapSignalR();  to Startup.cs fixed it Aravind Sivam. Thanks

Comment: this is the old way - this is obsolete if using `[OwinStartupAttribute]`

Answer (score 4):

It worked for me:

Go to the startup class in your project, in the Configuration method and add this:

app.MapSignalR("/signalr", new HubConfiguration());

I hope it works for you

Comment: This worked for me after all the above was explored! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try this and no need to write line in App-Start Event

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Faceless_Books.Hubs.Startup))]

namespace Faceless_Books.Hubs
{
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### If you are using Visual Studio 2012, the SignalR Hub Class (v2) template will not be available. You can add a plain Class called ChatHub instead.

**step to follow**

1) `In Solution Explorer, right-click the project, select **Add** | SignalR Hub Class (v2). Name the class ChatHub.cs`

2)**Modify class**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            // Call the broadcastMessage method to update clients.
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In mine, I had copy/pasted the name of the class from an example, but that's not what my class was named.

JS:

```
var notification = $.connection.notificationHub; // <--- my class is not called "NotificationHub"
```

C#:

```
public class ToastHub : Hub  // <--- should have been $.connection.toastHub above
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to disable request filtering in order to enable pull Hubs script

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <clear></clear>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>        
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```